# How to initialise own values instead of using Tsp.create_random_instance

Tags: qiskit

In Qiskit's tutorial 'Max-Cut and Traveling Salesman Problem', below code is used to create the nodes:

`tsp = Tsp.create_random_instance(n, seed=123)`

What information is being generated by this function and how to replace this function if I have my own set of data?

Answer (score 1):

The method `Tsp.create_random_instance()` creates a random instance of the TSP problem. Internally, it uses NetworkX's function [`random_geometric_graph()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.generators.geometric.random_geometric_graph.html).

To have your own graph, you can rely on NetworkX library as well to create it:

```
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()
graph.add_edges_from([[0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4]])
nx.draw(graph, with_labels = True)
```

[image]

Now, pass the graph to `Tsp` constructor

```
tsp_instance = Tsp(graph)
```

Another method to create your own problem instance is by creating a [TSPLIB](https://tsplib95.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) file then use `Tsp.parse_tsplib_format()` method.